# Method testing and nothing prints out

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm testing a part of my Sudoku program to test if the row is valid or not. The board from file method makes a 9x9 array, but I can't understand why when I try running this isValidRow() method there is no indication of it being true or false. Why is this so?

```
public static boolean isValidRow(int[][] grid, int row) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < 9){
        while (j < 9){
            if (grid[row][i] == grid[row][j]){
                if (i == j){
                    continue;
                }
                return false;
            }
            j++;    
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("hii");
    return true;    
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int[][] board = new int[9][9];
    boardFromFile(board, "sudoku.txt");
    System.out.println(isValidRow(board, 0));
}
```

Comment: What happened when you debugged and stepped through your code?

Comment: You need to show the code for `boardFromFile` the problem is likely caused by that

Comment: Also does it ever reach "hii"?

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop in `isValidRow()`.

When you first call this function `i` and `j` are both zero (0). Thus,

```
if (grid[row][i] == grid[row][j])
```

will always evaluate to `true`. As will:

```
if (i == j)
```

The next action is:

```
continue;
```

which will start the inner `while` loop again. And as `i` and `j` are unchanged the same thing will happen again and again.